# Database design for wishlist

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am currently working on small travel application in which users can add other users' trips in their wishlist. I am facing difficulty in designing database for wishlist.

What I have tried so far is:

```
 user (user_id(pk), user_name)

 trip(trip_id(pk), trip_name, user_id(fk))

 wishlist(trip_id(fk), user_id(fk))
```

But, since  multiple users can add multiple trips into their wishlist, How to associate these relations?

And if user retrieves his personal wishlist, the associated trips in the wishlist for 'that' particular user can be shown?

**EDIT:**

For clarification, the problem is: **One user can have multiple trips and many users can add each-other's trips to their one 'own' wishlist"**

Comment: take a cheat of paper and a pen, start to analyse and design your problem using Merise/UML or other methods, after that SQL will be easy.

Comment: @Begueradj plz tell me the answer if you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong about your design. You have a table of trips and every trip is related to the user who did it. And you have a table for wishes where every wish is a combination of wishing user and their desired trip.

Get a user's wish trips:

```
select *
from trip
where trip_id in (select trip_id from wishlist where user_id = 123);
```

So what problem do you see?

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? I ask "what problem do you see", you answer "no"??? Do you mean the query? Why shouldn't it work? Get all wishlist entries of user 123 and display the associated trips. It's as simple as this.

Comment: It is not simple as you think. for clarification, the problem is: "One user can have multiple trips and many users can add each-other's trips to their one 'own' wishlist".

Comment: No, it is that simple. 1. One user can have multiple trips. This is why user_id is a foreign key in trips. 2. One user can have multiple wish trips. This is why user_id is a foreign key in wishlist. 3. Each user has his/her own wishlist. Namely all records in wishlist for that user. 4. Many users can have the same wish. So there is more than one entry for that trip in wishlist. So again: Where is the problem? There is none. The database as designed by you seems perfect for the task.

Comment: Ya...the design is OK..But I tried different query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26654731/3960528

Comment: And I also asked modified question on dba.stackexchange. One of them answer was conflicting : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81476/51177 He is saying that my tables are not normalized. Can you review it? I'll highly appreciate.

Comment: Yes, of course there is not only one query you can use on your database. My query gives you the trips user 123 wishes. James Anderson's query that you reposted here, gives you all users with all their wishes. Pixelated's answer in dba.se to make a wishlist an entity that you can give a name, is also a valid idea, but not needed as you say. Briguy37's answer is also good: What shall your table names describe: the table or a record? So far you have a mix: user (each *record* is a user), trip (each *record* is a trip), wishlist (the *table* is a wishlist). So naming could be more consistent.

Comment: Yes you did now. So you see, there is not only one way to get to a user's wish trips. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick suggestion. You might possibly have a table to link the two.

```
User { user_id PK, user_name }
UserWishlist { id PK, wishlist_id FK, user_id FK }
Wishlist { wishlist_id PK, trip_id FK }

Trip { trip_id PK, user_id FK, trip_name }
```

Comment: So, will I need two tables for wishlisht - one for mapping trips to wishlist and another for mapping user to wishlist?

Comment: @user3828744: In my opinion the original design is much better than yours. In your design each wishlist only contains *one* trip. So a user has many wishlists only because they wish more than one trip. This is just the same thing as before only more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The design is OK. Nothing is wrong and I can fire following query for this:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name,trip_name

FROM user u
JOIN wishlist w ON u.user_id = w.user_id
JOIN trip t ON w.trip_id = t.trip_id
WHERE users.userid= current_user's_id
```

It works well.